Guide for Google OAuth 2.0 for ASP.NET Web API + React
I'm creating my app with an ASP.NET Web API + React. And I can't do Google OAuth 2.0. Can someone point to a guide, or explain how I need to do it?
I tried this, but I don't understand how I need to link it with React.
Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    //.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new    SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    })
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Google:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Google:ClientSecret"];
        options.CallbackPath = "/api/Authorization/GoogleResponse";
    })
    .AddFacebook(options =>
    {
        options.AppId = builder.Configuration["Facebook:AppId"];
        options.AppSecret = builder.Configuration["Facebook:AppSecret"];
        options.CallbackPath = "/api/authorization/FacebookCallback";
    });

Authorization controller:
[HttpGet("LoginGoogle")]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "/")
{
    //var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = returnUrl };
    //return Challenge(properties, "Google");

    string redirecturl = Url.ActionLink("GoogleResponse", "Authorization");
    var properties = signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties("Google", redirecturl);
    var chall = new ChallengeResult("Google", properties);
    return chall;
}   

[HttpGet("GoogleResponse")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleResponse()
{
    var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Google");

    if (!authenticateResult.Succeeded)
    {
        return BadRequest(new Error( "Failed to authenticate with Google" ));
    }

    var user = authenticateResult.Principal;
    authentication.LoginOrCreateUser(user);

    var token = authentication.CreateToken();

    return Ok(token);
}


define And I can't do Google OAuth 2.0. what exactly is your issue?
